Azure Steam Analytics Query
I want to store the below JSON data to the Azure table. Here the input and the output for Azure Stream Analytics are Azure IoT Hub and table respectively.
[
  {
    "device1": [
      {
        "name": "temperature",
        "value": 50
      },
      "name": "voltage",
      "value": 220
    }
  ],
  "device2": [
    {
      "name": "temperature",
      "value": 10
    },
    "name": "voltage",
    "value": 200
  }
]
}
]

final result would look like below image


I tried with simple json formate
  [{
    "messageId": messageId,
    "name": "temperature"
   }]



SELECT
    i.messageId AS messageId,
    i.name AS name,
    i.PartitionId,
    i.EventProcessedUtcTime,
    i.EventEnqueuedUtcTime
INTO
    [table]
FROM
    [input] i
    

But for nested and dynamic key data i am confused.


The Json that you have provided seems to be invalid.


For your case, you can use cross apply and getarrayelements to get each element of the array into a separate row.
Below is the similar sample Json, I tried with:
[
  {
    "device1": [
      {
        "name": "temperature",
        "value": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "voltage",
        "value": 220
      }
    ]
  }
]

Azure Stream analytics query to flatten this Json array:
select d1.arrayvalue.name as name, d1.arrayvalue.value as value, device='device1'
from input
cross apply getArrayelements(device1) as d1

Output:


Thank you @Aswin for your response, I added these lines of code. showing perfectly in Azure SAJ preview. But in the Azure Storage Account(table), it is showing only the last value i.e.  {
"name": "voltage",
"value": 220
}
look like
| name     | value |
| Voltage |  220   |

What is missing

name - temperate and value - 50  are missing

Thanks you so much @Aswin it is working. I have added id key to each object.

great to know, this is working for you

If this is working, you can mark this as answer by clicking the tick mark in the answer
